# How to make a DialogPreference that shows a Button next to an EditText?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, preference

Here's a problem which is driving me mad.

I have the need to have two slightly different (could pe a parametrized one) and very specific Preference types.

One is an EditText with a Button next to it.
The EditText lets you enter (modify) a phone number, while the button opens the Contacts dialog and lets you chooe a contact's number.

The other Preference is really similar, if not identical, but lets you choose an eMail, from **another** contact (It's not said that the phone and the eMail are from the same contact, they can - and normally should - be from different people).

These custom Preferences should work in PreferenceActivities as well as in PreferenceFragments.

Even better, if the EditText could also have the contact photo on the left - but this is just dreaming, I know...

Do you have any idea how can I accomplish something like that?
I can't even figure out if the best way to do this would be using intents in PreferenceScreen or extending a DialogPreference or ... who knows what.
Now, My English is maybe faulty, I better explain what I need by the help of an image (it's a sequence of actions):
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: when you need something more complex then don't use preferenceFragments - it will be simpler without it.

Comment: Well, you see... I HATE when it says: "This f#@@ing method has been deprecated". And Google's national sport is to deprecate everything. So, I do the "good boy" and use PreferenceActivities for older devices with Android 2.2+ and use PreferenceFragments with Android devices which use Android 3.0+ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turn out that DialogPreferences can't override onActivityResult, which is **crucial** for getting a result aftwer you picked a contact from the contact list.

So I had to resign and find some other solution.
A simple EditTextPreference was... too simple for my tastes, I extended a RingTonePreference and bent it to my needs.

You will need: a Class (the preference itself), a styleable attribute (just an enum to set wether it's used to pick a phone number or an email address) and the preference definition file.

Here we go:

CLS_Prefs_Contact.java

```
/**
 * CLS_Prefs_Contact class
 *
 * This is the class that allows for a custom Contact Picker Preference
 * (auto refresh summary).
 *
 * @category    Custom Preference
 * @author      Paranoid Eyes
 * @copyright   Paranoid Eyes
 * @version     1.0
 */
package com.paranoideyes.contactpreference_rt;

/* ---------------------------------- Imports ------------------------------- */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
* @attr ref android.R.styleable#ContactPreference_contactInfo
*/
public class ContactPreference extends RingtonePreference
{

    /* ----------------------------- Constants ------------------------------ */

    /*
    private static final String nsContact =
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lucacrisi.contactpreference_rt";
    */
    private static final String nsContact =
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";

    /* ----------------------------- Variables ------------------------------ */

    //private static Contact_Info contactInfo = null;
    private int contactInfo = 0;
    private final String defaultSummary = "---";

    /* ------------------------------ Objects ------------------------------- */

    private static Context ctx = null;

    private static SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    /* ---------------------------- Constructors ---------------------------- */

    public ContactPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        ctx = context;

        // Read attributes
        contactInfo = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(nsContact, "contactInfo", 0);

        //System.out.println("Constructor - " + contactInfo);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);

        summary_Update();
    }

    /* ----------------------------- Overrides ------------------------------ */

    @Override
    public final boolean onActivityResult
        (final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                //
                getContactInfo(data);

                //
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                if (callChangeListener(uri != null ? uri.toString() : ""))
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected final void onPrepareRingtonePickerIntent(final Intent tnt)
    {
        tnt.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        tnt.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    }

    /* ------------------------------ Methods ------------------------------- */

    private final void getContactInfo(final Intent data)
    {
        //final String noData = getString(R.string.missing_data);
        //String result = noData;
        String result = "";

        final Cursor cur =
            ctx.getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            final String contactId =
                cur.getString
                (
                    cur.getColumnIndex
                    (
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                    )
                );

            //System.out.println("getContactInfo - " + contactInfo);

            switch(contactInfo)
            {
                case 0: // phone
                {
                    // Find the phone numbers
                    String hasPhone = cur.getString
                        (
                            cur.getColumnIndex
                            (
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                            )
                        );
                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hasPhone = "false" ;
                    }
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone))
                    {
                        final Cursor phones = ctx.getContentResolver().query
                            (
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +
                                " = " + contactId, null, null
                            );
                        String number = ""; //noData;
                        if (phones.getCount() > 0)
                        {
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            number = phones.getString
                                (
                                    phones.getColumnIndex
                                    (
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                                    )
                                );
                        }
                        phones.close();
                        result = number;
                        //result = ((number == "") ? noData : number);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 1: // email
                {
                    // Find the email addresses
                    final Cursor emails = ctx.getContentResolver().query
                        (
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID +
                            " = " + contactId, null, null
                        );
                    String email = ""; //noData;
                    if (emails.getCount() > 0)
                    {
                        emails.moveToFirst();
                        email = emails.getString
                            (
                                emails.getColumnIndex
                                (
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
                                )
                            );
                    }
                    emails.close();
                    result = email;
                    //result = ((email == "") ? noData : email);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();

        // Here do the magic and put the value into the Preferences
        setting_Write(getKey(), result);

        summary_Update();
    }

    private final static void setting_Write(final String key, final String value)
    {
        // Write the value
        prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    private final void summary_Update()
    {
        // Read the value and set the summary
        String str = prefs.getString(getKey(), "");
        if ("".equals(str))
        {
            str = defaultSummary;
        }
        setSummary(str);
    }
}
```

res/values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CLS_Prefs_Contact">
        <attr name="contactInfo">
            <enum name="phone" value="0" />
            <enum name="email" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

res/xml/prefs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:contact="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <com.paranoideyes.contactpreference_rt.CLS_Prefs_Contact
        android:key="phone_nr"
        android:title="@string/phone_nr"
        contact:contactInfo="phone"
    />
    <com.paranoideyes.contactpreference_rt.CLS_Prefs_Contact
        android:key="email_ad"
        android:title="@string/email_ad"
        contact:contactInfo="email"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ContactPreference Sample</string>

    <string name="phone_nr">Choose a phone number</string>
    <string name="summary_pn">Not set</string>

    <string name="email_ad">Choose an email</string>
    <string name="summary_ea">Not set</string>
</resources>
```

So, this is what I ended up with:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...its looking gud... Do you have a sample project somewhere for it..??

Comment: Maybe I can put something together in a day or two. Then send it as a zipped project via eMail, if you agree. Please note that my picker only gets the **FIRST** phone or eMail for a contact. I'm still studying a better way, to **open a second window** with a list of all the available phones or eMails to choose from.

Comment: It would still be useful to pick first only...and gladly waiting for this effort for me...here is my email: umairprivacy@gmail.com

Comment: OK, please allow me some days to prepare it (I have to 1 - manage my time; 2 - collect it from an existing project).

Comment: Ah... the finger is not included (it was added just to show interaction)... ;)

Comment: So you don't need it anymore? I have a zipped one... oh, well, good that you made it with your powers. It's a training.

Comment: Yeah, actually i realized that i have time limitations...so i tried and it worked...many thanks for you interest...:)

Comment: It was a really comprehensive Android Master Class. Thank you.